# Combine value part of Tuple2 which is a map, into single map grouping by the key of Tuple2

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, databricks

I am doing this in Scala and Spark.

I have and `Dataset` of `Tuple2` as `Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])]`.

Below is and example of the values in the `Dataset`.

```
(A, {1->100, 2->200, 3->100})
(B, {1->400, 4->300, 5->900})
(C, {6->100, 4->200, 5->100})
(B, {1->500, 9->300, 11->900})
(C, {7->100, 8->200, 5->800})
```

If you notice, the key or first element of the Tuple can be repeated. Also, the corresponding map of the same Tuples' key can have duplicate keys in the map (second part of Tuple2).

I want to create a final `Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])]`. And the output should be as below (from the above example). Also, the last keys' value of the map is retained (check B and C) and previous same key against B and C is removed.

```
(A, {1->100, 2->200, 3->100})
(B, {4->300, 1->500, 9->300, 11->900, 5->900})
(C, {6->100, 4->200, 7->100, 8->200, 5->800})
```

Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using rdd,

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    Seq(("A", Map(1->100, 2->200, 3->100)),
        ("B", Map(1->400, 4->300, 5->900)),
        ("C", Map(6->100, 4->200, 5->100)),
        ("B", Map(1->500, 9->300, 11->900)),
        ("C", Map(7->100, 8->200, 5->800)))
)

rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => a ++ b).collect()

// Array((A,Map(1 -> 100, 2 -> 200, 3 -> 100)), (B,Map(5 -> 900, 1 -> 500, 9 -> 300, 11 -> 900, 4 -> 300)), (C,Map(5 -> 800, 6 -> 100, 7 -> 100, 8 -> 200, 4 -> 200)))
```

and using dataframe,

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    Seq(("A", Map(1->100, 2->200, 3->100)),
        ("B", Map(1->400, 4->300, 5->900)),
        ("C", Map(6->100, 4->200, 5->100)),
        ("B", Map(1->500, 9->300, 11->900)),
        ("C", Map(7->100, 8->200, 5->800)))
).toDF("key", "map")

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy","LAST_WIN")

df.withColumn("map", map_entries($"map"))
  .groupBy("key").agg(collect_list($"map").alias("map"))
  .withColumn("map", flatten($"map"))
  .withColumn("map", map_from_entries($"map")).show(false)

+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|key|map                                                |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|B  |[1 -> 500, 4 -> 300, 5 -> 900, 9 -> 300, 11 -> 900]|
|C  |[6 -> 100, 4 -> 200, 5 -> 800, 7 -> 100, 8 -> 200] |
|A  |[1 -> 100, 2 -> 200, 3 -> 100]                     |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. Can I do this using DF/DS?

Comment: @vijayinani yeah **Datasets** also have a `groupBy` and `reduceValues` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Using dataframes:

```scala
val df = Seq(("A", Map(1 -> 100, 2 -> 200, 3 -> 100)),
    ("B", Map(1 -> 400, 4 -> 300, 5 -> 900)),
    ("C", Map(6 -> 100, 4 -> 200, 5 -> 100)),
    ("B", Map(1 -> 500, 9 -> 300, 11 -> 900)),
    ("C", Map(7 -> 100, 8 -> 200, 5 -> 800))).toDF("a", "b")

val df2 = df.select('a, explode('b))
    .groupBy("a", "key")           //remove the duplicate keys
    .agg(last('value).as("value")) //and take the last value for duplicate keys
    .groupBy("a")
    .agg(map_from_arrays(collect_list('key), collect_list('value)).as("b"))
df2.show()
```

prints

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|a  |b                                                  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|B  |[5 -> 900, 9 -> 300, 1 -> 500, 4 -> 300, 11 -> 900]|
|C  |[6 -> 100, 8 -> 200, 7 -> 100, 4 -> 200, 5 -> 800] |
|A  |[3 -> 100, 1 -> 100, 2 -> 200]                     |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

As there are two aggregations involved, the rdd based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647725/2129801) is likely to be faster