# Split Map type column with huge values into multiple rows using Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

This is in continuation of the question: [Combine value part of Tuple2 which is a map, into single map grouping by the key of Tuple2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647473/combine-value-part-of-tuple2-which-is-a-map-into-single-map-grouping-by-the-key)

I am now able to reduce the rows by using `reduceByKey`.

But now, in the final `DataFrame`...

e.g.

```
(A, {1->100, 2->200, 3->100})
(B, {4->300, 1->500, 9->300, 11->900, 5->900, 6-> 111, 7-> 222, 8-> 333, 12-> 444, 13->555, 19->666})
(C, {6->100, 4->200, 7->100, 8->200, 5->800})
```

...some rows have the map column with very large map. For e.g. for `B` above.

I am trying to write the DF to Azure Cosmos DB Core SQL. Here each row from the above DF turns into 1 document of Cosmos DB. The issue is if the row size is more than 2MB, then, Cosmos DB rejects the request.

Question: I want to split rows with huge map columns into multiple rows (so that they become less than 2MB in size). Duplicate key column is not an issue.

The final result can be (if I divide the map if it has more than 5 elements everytime):

```
(A, {1->100, 2->200, 3->100})
(B, {4->300, 1->500, 9->300, 11->900, 5->900})
(B, {6-> 111, 7-> 222, 8-> 333, 12-> 444, 13->555})
(B, {19->666})
(C, {6->100, 4->200, 7->100, 8->200, 5->800})
```

You may ask that in the previous question, it was already split, then why did I merge? The reason is in the previous question, for B, without **reduceByKey**, I may have 1000 rows. But, finally I only need 20 rows for example as above. 1 row would have been ideal but due to Cosmos limit, I have to create multiple documents (each less than 2MB).

Hope I am clear. Please let me know for any clarification required.

Comment: @Lamanus - please suggest

Comment: @werner - please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by writing my own custom code as below:

```
originalDF.rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => a ++ b).map(row => {
  val indexedMapEntries: Map[Int, (String, String)] = row._2.zipWithIndex.map(mapWithIndex => (mapWithIndex._2, mapWithIndex._1))
  var min = 0
  var max = Math.min(indexedMapEntries.size - 1, 9999)
  var proceed = true

  var rowKeyIdToAttributesMapList: ListBuffer[(String, Map[String, String])] = new ListBuffer[(String, Map[String, String])]()

  while (proceed) {

    var tempMapToHoldEntries = Map[String, String]()
    var i = min
    while (i <= max) {
      var entry: (String, String) = indexedMapEntries.get(i).get
      tempMapToHoldEntries += entry
      i = i + 1
    }
    rowKeyIdToAttributesMapList += ((row._1, tempMapToHoldEntries))
    min = max + 1
    max = Math.min(indexedMapEntries.size - 1, max + 9999)
    if (min > (indexedMapEntries.size - 1))
      proceed = false

  }

  rowKeyIdToAttributesMapList.toList

}).flatMap(x => x).toDF("rowKeyId", "attributes")
```

Here, the `originalDF` is the one from my previous question (check OP). `10000` is the maximum  size of each map for a `rowKeyId`. If the map size exceeds 10000, then I create a new row with same rowKeyId and remaining attributes in loop.